# Is there any multiDexEnabled behavior difference in debug and release mode?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-multidex

Recently I developed app with just 3-4 screens. On click Signup button, Signup screen will get open.

In release mode App was crashing on click of Signup button where I have written code to start Signup screen.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SignUpScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_DATA, bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Same code is running in debug mode. To find root cause I set debuggable true in release mode. Result was surprising, it started working.

After spending time i got solution that I need to set multiDexEnabled true in build.gradle. After doing that app started working in release mode with debuggable false.

Question is, how does multiDexEnabled help to run app in release mode?

Why and where to use multiDexEnabled?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: @NileshRathod - I have already refer that link. Read question properly.

Comment: post logcat error. Because I have experienced with this issue in socket connect past month.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya How could I get logcat error. If i set debuggable true in release mode app is working. And with debuggable false, you cannot get any log of app.

Comment: you can get log even if release mode. set "NO FILTERS" instead of "Show only Selected Application".